# How to serve different folders according the request in Express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I really don't get how to achieve something that would work like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  if(whateverYouDreamOf){
    res.redirect('http://www.subdomain.example.com');
  }else if(something){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app1'));
  }else{
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app2'));
  }
}
```

I need to serve different folders according a lot of parameters but I'm stuck. So a working example would be great.

**EDIT**

This example doesn't serve multiple files properly with Mukesh Sharma method:

PATH:

```
           example folder
         /       |       \
        /        |        \
       /         |         \
server.js | public folder | node_modules
            /    |    \
           /     |     \
          /      |      \
index.html | style.css | game.js
```

HTML/CSS/JS: https://jsfiddle.net/gmye9er5/2/

SERVER:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

app.use('*', function(req, res, next){
   return express.static(__dirname + '/public')(req, res, next);
});

server.listen(3000, /*your IP*/);
```

Comment: This code is fundamentally flawed because it appears you're trying to do `app.use(express.static(...))` behavior for one user or one request and it simply doesn't work that way.  Once you run an `app.use(express.static(...))`, it's in force for the rest of your server process' lifetime for all users.  I rather doubt that is what you want.

Comment: So, please back up and explain in words what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Also, if you show us what the actual `if` statements are looking at, we may be able to find a built-in way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah I don't want that. I want to serve all files of a folder or not in function of the user request, instead of sending  each files separately. I'm looking for the fastest way to wrap all files of this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this useful.

```
app.use('*', function(req, res, next){
   if(whateverYouDreamOf){
      res.redirect('http://www.subdomain.example.com');
   } else if(something){
      return express.static(__dirname + '/app1')(req, res, next);
   }else{
      return express.static(__dirname + '/app2')(req, res, next);
   }
});
```

Comment: sorry for the delay, I'm testing it currently

Comment: Doesn't `express.static()` expect a `next` argument and isn't one needed?

Comment: I've accepted your answer because I forget to remove this line app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app1')); in front of your code. now that I removed it it doesn't serve files properly. I'm probably wrong somewhere. I will continue further testing. If it still doesn't do it, I'll tell you.

Comment: its working fine for me. You can pass `next` to it, if you want to.

Comment: it works fine with app.use(express.static..., but with your code I get some of the files and it makes this weird tree in the devs tools https://i.imgur.com/JYPAg3H.png  and those error logs https://i.imgur.com/yLf47eG.png

Comment: and    `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:`